# Profile page style is broken with too many negative votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, profile-page, design

Tested in latest version of Chrome on Mac OS X.

[image: Broken Profile page]

It certainly argues for SO's question quality that this hasn't been noticed before :-)

Comment: Ahhahaha! Good catch.

Comment: Looks right in Chrome 6 on Linux

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720270/symbol-appear-in-index

Comment: @SLaks: Prime example of why question rep is overrated, even at 5 points. To ask something like *that*, and have 1700+ rep? xRobot has 242 questions and 0 answers...

Comment: @MPelletier - How about this user: http://stackoverflow.com/users/39677/blankman (1174 questions, 5 answers)? They'll soon have access to 10k capabilities.

Comment: @BradLarson: Egad. I've sorta been fiddling with that over at SEDE. I thought I could plot where user rep comes from. I might pick it up again.

Comment: There have been style changes recently, this *shouldn't* be an issue anymore, but can you confirm on OSX?