# Minor layout problem with negative votes

Tags: bug, status-completed, information-display, design

At the risk of rubbing salt into Rook's current status in the primaries, is this a formatting/layout bug?:
[image]
The negative sign is sitting on top of the overall vote count instead of to the left.

Comment: Related, as this can apparently break for 2 digits on profile pages - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75333/profile-page-style-is-broken-with-too-many-negative-votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the election page we no longer show negatively voted nomination scores. The lowest you can go is zero.

Answer (score 13):

[image: −∞]

Fixed.

Answer (score 5):

<strike>Clearly a case of a plain old space when a non-breaking space would be preferred.</strike>

Looks like they need to change a plain old hyphen (-) to an html minus entity (− `&#8722;`).

Comment: @Joel, not necessary true.  Lots of browsers will break a hyphen character regardless of a space or not.

Comment: @Justin You can use CSS or the HTML `style=` attribute to tell the renderer not to line-break.

Comment: @Justin Viewing source, I see you are right.  There's no whitespace at all there.  They need to change the hyphen to a minus entity (&#8722;)

Comment: @Joel, I believe there has already been a question on meta about that.

Comment: @Justin I recall the question as well.  I can't find it now, but it was presented on aethsetic/semantic grounds rather than layout problems. I'm inclined to actually close the original as a duplicate of this one if I can find it, because this version of the question has a chance of being addressed.

Comment: Found it! - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/71269/aesthetic-issue-negative-vote-counts-should-use-minus-sign-u2212-instead-of-h