# Vote count creating second line

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design, vote-count

I just saw this:

[image]

This isn't a dupe of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/76482/) question, by the way, because the issue was apparently resolved.

[Here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed) is the post. I'm on Chrome 15.0.874.121.

Comment: Actually I think the issue in the linked case was just swept under the rug: "we no longer show negatively voted nomination scores".

Comment: It does not do this for me: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99062/dont-close-questions-where-the-user-has-requested-that-it-not-be-closed

Comment: It really helps if you include your browser / version / etc when reporting design bugs.

Comment: Doesnt happen for me on Chromium

Comment: Who would've thought that "On the election page we no longer show negatively voted nomination scores. The lowest you can go is zero." wouldn't be a long-term solution to this bug

Comment: This is how I see that question's score using Safari 5.1.2 on Mac OS X 10.7.2.

Comment: Happens in IE 8 and 9 as well

Comment: The issue was "resolved" by not displaying the vote count when it went under 0. Nothing like sweeping stuff under the rug.

Comment: No repro with FF8, looks totally fine.

Comment: I don't see this in Chrome 16 either, don't have a machine with 15 to test with.

Comment: On Linux: Chromium 14 shows the line break, Chrome 16.0.912.63 beta does not.

Answer (score 6):

Adding `white-space: nowrap` to `.vote-count-post` fixes it.

I'm not sure if this causes any unwanted side effects elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't exist anymore.  There have been many, many css changes since 2011, so no doubt this got picked up somewhere along the way.