# Three-figure negative score doesn't fit in score box without wrapping

Tags: bug, information-display

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Vote count creating second line](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116215/vote-count-creating-second-line)

Here's how a negative three-figure score looks in the question list:

[image: 3-digit negative]

And here's how it looks on the question page:

[image: 3-digit negative]

I'm curious to see the how the split score gets formatted, but I don't have enough rep.

Perhaps a smaller font could be used when the score gets lower than -99.

This is with IE 8, and the zoom level is 100%.

Yeah, I'm officially avoiding work.

Comment: `white-space: nowrap;`

Comment: Here it is: [Vote count creating second line](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116215/vote-count-creating-second-line).  Looks like the answer was the same as @Chichiray is mentioning (although nothing was ever done about it).

Comment: @Igby - Other solutions include upvoting or deleting the question. :-) This question is bad on purpose just to see how much rep you can lose on downvotes.

Comment: Yes, I can see that. But this is about the formatting of the score, not the question itself.